# HuggingFace Training using GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Based on [HuggingFace script](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/language-modeling) to train a transformers model from scratch.
I run:

```
python3 run_mlm.py \
--dataset_name wikipedia \
--tokenizer_name roberta-base \
--model_type roberta \
--dataset_config_name 20200501.en \
--do_train \
--do_eval \
--learning_rate 1e-5 \
--num_train_epochs 5 \
--save_steps 5000 \
--warmup_steps=10000 \ 
--seed 666 \
--gradient_accumulation_steps=4 \ 
--output_dir models/mlm_wikipedia_scratch/ \
--per_gpu_train_batch_size 8
```

I don't understand why I can't see my python3 process on GPU running `nvidia-smi`
Here a screen:
[image: top | nvidia-smi | training_script]

Comment: Which script are you executing? I don't see `training_mlm.py` among the list of files of the repo that you are pointing to.

Comment: Sorry, I just copy and paste my cmd (and I renamed the file in my folder). I run `run_mlm.py`. Have to edit the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure the followings are correct:

1. GPU is correctly installed on your environment

```
In [1]: import torch
In [2]: torch.cuda.is_available()
Out[2]: True
```

2. Specify the GPU you want to use:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=X        # X = 0, 1 or 2
echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES           # Testing: Should display the GPU you set
```

Run the script again and it should work.